# Time Format and value mapping Not Working in the fragment UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have fragment as mentioned below. I am mapping from a model --> myTable.
The columns are visible accept Start Time. I tried different approach for that column. Can any one find the mistake in the code. Below is the JSON Structure :

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Page id="jobTableDisplayPage" showHeader="false" enableScrolling="true">
        <content>
            <Table id="jobTable" items="{myTable>/d/results/}">
                <columns>
                    <Column width="15em">
                        <Text text="Job Name" />
                    </Column>
                    <Column width="5em">
                        <Text text="User Name" />
                    </Column>
                    <Column width="5em">
                        <Text text="Job Status" />
                    </Column>
                    <Column width="5em">
                        <Text text="Start Date" />
                    </Column>
                    <Column width="5em">
                        <Text text="Start Time" />
                    </Column>
                    <Column width="5em">
                        <Text text="End Time" />
                    </Column>
                    <Column width="5em">
                        <Text text="Spool Number" />
                    </Column>
                </columns>
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem>
                        <cells>
                            <Text text="{myTable>Jobname}" />
                            <Text text="{myTable>Usern}" />
                            <Text text="{myTable>Status}" />
                            <Text text="{myTable>Startdate}" />
                            <Text
                                text="{  path: '{myTable>Starttime}',
                                         type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Time',
                                         formatOptions: {
                                               relative: true,
                                               relativeScale: 'auto'
                                       }
                                     }" />
                            <Text text="{myTable>Endtime}" />
                            <Text text="{myTable>Spool}" />
                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
        </content>
    </Page>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

The columns are visible accept Start Time. I tried different approach for that column. Can any one find the mistake in the code. Below is the JSON Structure :

```
{  
   "d":{  
      "results":[  
         {  
            "__metadata":{  
               "id":"blablabla",
               "uri":"blablabla",
               "type":"blablabla"
            },
            "Jobname":"JOB1",
            "Usern":"BC-BATCH",
            "Status":"F",
            "Startdate":"10/27/2017",
            "Starttime":"PT03H00M49S",
            "Endtime":"PT03H31M12S",
            "Spool":"0000033977"
         },
         {  
            "__metadata":{  
               "id":"blablabla",
               "uri":"blablabla",
               "type":"blablabla"
            },
            "Jobname":"JOB2",
            "Usern":"BC-BATCH",
            "Status":"F",
            "Startdate":"10/27/2017",
            "Starttime":"PT03H00M49S",
            "Endtime":"PT03H31M12S",
            "Spool":"0000033977"
         }

      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Add Date / Time from an Odata Service Correctly into the UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593990/how-to-add-date-time-from-an-odata-service-correctly-into-the-ui)

Comment: Did the below answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48251335/

Answer (score 0):

I believe `path` doesn't need the curly brackets.

Try:

`<Text text="{ path: 'myTable>Starttime', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Time',
      formatOptions: { relative: true, relativeScale: 'auto' } }" />`

Comment: Nope it does not work without curly brackets either... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47603778/5846045), you need to use the [odata binding type](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type/overview) instead of the regular one.

So, in case of the odata type [*Edm.Time*](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/333a9dac5a614b1590c61916c9cecbf5) (`Starttime` and `Startdate` in your case):

<s>`type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Time',`</s> --> `type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.Time',`

And yes, the additional curly brackets around the `path` are invalid. So it should be:

```
<Text text="{
  path: 'myTable>Starttime',
  type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.Time',
  formatOptions: {
    relative: true
  }
}"/>
```